# Am not able to copy file names into into text directory from SFTP directory in unix (send "ls -lt *.csv > ${FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST}\r")

Tags: unix, expect

I want to move all `.csv` files into `$FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST` with `send "ls -lt *.csv > ${FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST}\r"`. It's not throwing any error but also not moving any of the files into local directory $FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST.

Please help me.

**EDIT**:
I want to get the list of files into local directory .PFB..

```
expect<<EOD 
spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=22 ${USER}@${HOST_NAME}
expect "password:" 
send "${PASSWD}\r" 
expect "sftp>" 
send "ls -la *.csv > ${FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST}\r" 
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r" 
EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few options, the best would be the next. Using

```
ssh host@remote "ls -lt /directory/of/log/*.csv" > $FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST
```

assuming `$FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST` is a file on your machine. If you want to setup cron job for this and if you are completely sure you want to do it!!!! you can do something like

```
ssh host:password@remote "ls -lt /directory/of/log/*.csv" > $FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST
```

This way you won't get prompted for password, really useful for cron jobs, but be aware, the password will be visible to anyone that opens the script file. Writing it somewhere else wouldn't help either, because it could be tracked down easily.

If you don't need it to be a cron job, you can do something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
function getlogs() {
    ssh username:$1@hostname "ls -lt /directory/of/log/*.csv" > $FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST
}
```

Then you can always do in terminal

```
getlogs password
```

This is the way I would do it.

Comment: In remote directory(SFTP) we shouldn't delete ,actually what am trying to do is we need to copy .csv files from SFTP directory to our local direcotry.so we are copying the files into varaible($FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST/). I could the list of files in log but not moving to local directory . ls -la *.csv > /***/**/***/log/9006_feedback_files_list.txt     ---- >FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST

Comment: Thanks, But the we can't use scp command in remote directory(SFTP>) .My point is i want to get the list of files into local directory .PFB..expect<<EOD
spawn /usr/bin/sftp -o Port=22 ${USER}@${HOST_NAME}
expect "password:"
send "${PASSWD}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "ls -la *.csv > ${FEEDBACK_FILE_LIST}\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD

Comment: Oh, you want just a list of files, not to copy the files?

Comment: Yes want to list the files into local directory but its not happens..Can u please help me.

Comment: No problem. Just let me know if this is a one time job or should be done on regular basis. So i can provide better answer

Comment: This is regular

Comment: Ok, I will answer you in 15 hours because I am currently not at a computer and typing out on phone would take ages. Is it ok?

Comment: yeah its fine not an issue. i need to get list of files into local directory which is text file